# Angular imported modules do not wait for APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, auth0

I'm trying to use the `auth0/auth0-angular` library in an Angular 11 app.

I'm following the section on [loading config dynamically](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular/blob/75493d0fdad6c1bfc0abe14b21fbe649d8f3aa2e/README.md#dynamic-configuration).

It provides this example app module code:

```
// app.module.ts
// ---------------------------
import { AuthModule, AuthClientConfig } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';

// Provide an initializer function that returns a Promise
function configInitializer(
  handler: HttpBackend,
  config: AuthClientConfig
) {
  return () =>
    new HttpClient(handler)
      .get('/config')
      .toPromise()
      .then((loadedConfig: any) => config.set(loadedConfig));   // Set the config that was loaded asynchronously here
}

// Provide APP_INITIALIZER with this function. Note that there is no config passed to AuthModule.forRoot
imports: [
  // other imports..

  HttpClientModule,
  AuthModule.forRoot(),   //<- don't pass any config here
],
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: configInitializer,    // <- pass your initializer function here
    deps: [HttpBackend, AuthClientConfig],
    multi: true,
  },
],
```

In short, it uses an `APP_INITIALIZER` provider to dynamically load config via a `Promise`, and this should complete before the Auth0 library's `AuthModule` is instantiated, so that it has the appropriate Auth0 config values loaded from an API and `AuthClientConfig.set(...)` has been called with those values in advance.

The [Angular APP_INITIALIZER documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) says:

> If any of these functions returns a Promise, initialization does not complete until the Promise is resolved.

So, their example makes sense on the face of it.

However, when I try to actually implement this solution in my own app I get the following error:

```
Error: Configuration must be specified either through AuthModule.forRoot or through AuthClientConfig.set
```

This suggests that the `AuthModule` has been instantiated before the config has been loaded and set.

It seems to me that Angular is not actually waiting for the `Promise` to resolve before it begins instantiating imported modules.

I think that this [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zld681?file=src/app/app.module.ts) demonstrates the problem in a simplified example without any of the Auth0 dependencies.

In this example, I would expect that `TestModule` is not instantiated until after the `Promise` has resolved, so I should see the following console output:

```
Inside factory method
Inside promise
Inside timeout
TestModule constructor
```

But what I actually see is this:

```
TestModule constructor
Inside factory method
Inside promise
Inside timeout
```

Could someone please help me to understand the exact nature of `APP_INITIALIZER`, i.e. when is it called, when does Angular wait for the `Promise` to resolve, when does Angular begin instantiating other modules, why might my Auth0 setup not be loading correctly, etc.?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**TL;DR** - I ended up solving this by loading the config in `main.ts` before bootstrapping the application and then making the config available via a custom injection token and then my app config service doesn't need to wait for it to load via HTTP as it's already available.

**The details**

A snippet of my `AppConfig` interface:

```
export interface AppConfig {
  auth: {
    auth0_audience: string,
    auth0_domain: string,
    auth0_client_id: string,
  };
}
```

The custom `InjectionToken` in my constants file:

```
 const APP_CONFIG: InjectionToken<AppConfig>
  = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('Application Configuration');
```

`main.ts`:

```
fetch('/config.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((config: AppConfig) => {
    if (environment.production) {
      enableProdMode();
    }

    platformBrowserDynamic([
      { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: config },
    ])
      .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  });
```

And then in my main `AppModule` I import the Auth0 `AuthModule.forRoot()` without config and call my own `AppConfigService` to configure the `AuthModule`.

I still need the `APP_INITIALIZER` to depend on `AppConfigService` and to return a `Promise` which somehow makes Angular wait until the `AppConfigService` *constructor* has been called, but it otherwise doesn't do anything (and still doesn't delay `AuthModule` being initialised), so I just resolve it immediately.

`AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => () => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          resolve();
        });
      },
      deps: [ AppConfigService ],
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Finally, the `AppConfigService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {

  constructor(
    @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private readonly appConfig: AppConfig,
    private authClientConfig: AuthClientConfig,
  ) {
    this.authClientConfig.set({
      clientId: this.appConfig.auth.auth0_client_id,
      domain: this.appConfig.auth.auth0_domain,
      audience: this.appConfig.auth.auth0_audience,
      httpInterceptor: {
        allowedList: [
          ...
        ],
      },
    });
  }
}
```

This all seems to work fine, although I still don't understand the exact nature of `APP_INITIALIZER` and I'm not very happy calling the Auth0 client config's `set` method in a constructor rather than an asynchronous "load" method like the documentation suggests.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for this. I spent all day, trying to get an APP_INITIALIZER to fire (with no success). Using the main.ts method, I was able to Inject the AppConfig class. I didn't need the APP_INITIALIZER step as the config gets injected straight into the Auth0AuthService, which then uses it to create the WebAuth client.

Comment: @AdamHardy Do you have maybe any snippet for your solution?

Comment: This is the same approach we are using before I upgraded our Angular version and NgRX.
`angular` 13.x to 14.x `@auth0/angular` 1.7.0 to 1.11.1 `@ngrx/effects` 12.x to 14.x.
After the upgrade, the same issue occur `Error: Configuration must be specified either through AuthModule.forRoot or through AuthClientConfig.set`. I got it working again. See details in my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76566508/10546462

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to wrap that api call in a Promise.

```
function configInitializer(handler: HttpBackend, config: AuthClientConfig) {
  return () => fetchAndSetConfig(handler, config);
}

function fetchAndSetConfig() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     new HttpClient(handler).get('/config').toPromise()
       .then((loadedConfig: any) => {
          config.set(loadedConfig);
          resolve(true);
      }); 
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Then you just have a promise waiting on another promise.  Angular should wait on the outer promise which is only resolved when the inner promise completes and resolves it.  I tried your approach with my main project and with the StackBlitz example and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the dynamic auth0 config. I've tried [this solution](https://medium.com/@philip_lysenko/initial-auth-with-angular-oauth2-a8740efe9264) by [Philip Lysenko](https://medium.com/@philip_lysenko). The main idea is to use lazy loading for the main route. It works for me.

And one more, set `initialNavigation: 'enabledNonBlocking'` for your root router configuration.

How it looks on the Network tab: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvMe3.png)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Dmytro.  I took another approach in the end because I wasn't comfortable with the lazy loading approach - it seemed like a large structural change that was a bit overkill for this scenario.