# `APP_INITIALIZER` vs (`platformBrowserDynamic` with `provide`)

Tags: javascript, angular

I already know that I can postpone an Angular bootstrap until a Promise or Obseravable are resolved.

Example :

<kbd>app.module.ts</kbd>

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigurationService) => ()=> configService.load(),
  deps: [ConfigurationService],
  multi: true
}
```

But i've seen this other approach of using `platformBrowserDynamic`'s providers :

example :

<kbd>`main.ts`:</kbd>

```
  (function () {
  return new Promise((resolver) => {
    const someData = {...}

    window.setTimeout(() => //simulate ajax data fetch
    {
      resolver(someData );
    }, 1000);
  });
})()
  .then((myData:any) => platformBrowserDynamic([ {provide: 'pbdProvider', useValue: myData  }]).bootstrapModule(...)
```

**Question:**

When should I use `APP_INITIALIZER` vs (`platformBrowserDynamic` with `provide`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing with `APP_INITIALIZER` that it does not guarantee the bootstrap of lazy loaded modules. For example, if the user loads a lazy loaded path this module will be loaded without waiting for the the requests that `APP_INITIALIZER` has started.

Thats why the `platformBrowserDynamic` is preferred when you want to be sure that all the data is fetched. The only downside of this approach can be the blank screen if the request takes too long or not access into angular injection capabilities.

[Angular imported modules do not wait for APP_INITIALIZER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66859984/angular-imported-modules-do-not-wait-for-app-initializer)

Answer (score 2):

#### Using the `APP_INITIALIZER`

The `APP_INITIALIZER` from Angular allows you to load things before your app starts. This might fill your needs, Since the `APP_INITIALIZER` also supports Observables, it got even handier and easier to use.

The problem with this approach is that when you have a module in the imports array which has a `forRoot(...)` method and you want to pass some data into it, which is loaded in the `APP_INITIALIZER` you have a `chicken-egg-problem`.
The AppModule needs to gather all modules in the imports array and therefore, also runs the `forRoot(...)`s, if any, but the info to pass it to `forRoot(...)`s can only be gathered when the `APP_INITIALIZER` has been called. But to call this, the `forRoot(...)` has to have the info first, etc.

#### Using `platformBrowserDynamic()`

Angulars `platformBrowserDynamic()` takes an optional parameter called `extraProviders?: StaticProvider[]`, which we can use to pass extra providers. We can use the Fetch API to load our data, and when it is loaded, bootstrap our application and provide the config. then load the `APP_INITIALIZER` with ready data that you can use with any provider later.

Comment: Will it be possible to show the problem in stackblitz  please ?